# Image Upload Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have got a problem about uploading image in laravel. I have done it many times but I don't have any idea what's the problem is

So here is my form:

```
<form action="/change" method="POST">
<input type="file" name ='img'>
</form>
```

Here is my controller:

```
    if($request->hasFile('img')) {
        $user_img_name = $request->file('img');
        $user_name = time().'.'.$user_img_name->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $user_img_name->move($destinationPath, $user_name);

        $user->user_pic = $user_name;

      }


    $user->save();
```

If I'm doing `dd($request)` before the if statement, it shows me that in 
`request->parameters->img` file is not null. There is an image, but the if statement does not catch. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `name ='img'`  there's a space... is that the issue?

Comment: this has no incidence

Comment: Your <form is missing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see that you're missing the enctype from your form, this is essential for file uploads:

```
<form action="/change" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name ='img'>
</form>
```

Comment: also don't forget the csrf token hidden input

Comment: hey @AlexTsirikidze - could you please accept this as the correct answer please? thanks :)